# Problems with making time delay

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to displey a few `labels` for exact amount of time and than forget them. I tried with `sleep()` and `time.sleep()`, but the program started after time I have defined and than executes lines. Here is part of my program:

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x700+400+100')
root.overrideredirect(1)
myFrame=Frame(root)
label1=Label(myFrame, text='Warning!', font=('Arial Black', '26'), fg='red')


myFrame.pack()
label1.pack()

sleep(10)



myFrame.pack_forget()
label1.pack_forget()
```

But when I run the program it wait for 10 seconds and than executes the lines (`frame` and `label` are packed and than immediatly forget).

I hope it is clear, what problem I have.

Comment: @DonkeyKong I want to display label1 for 10 seconds and than forget it.

Comment: And what is happening with your current code?

Comment: @DonkeyKong like I said: 10 sec it do nothing and than executes all the program I wrote (make root, set its geometry, etc.), but label1 is (I think so) packed (`.pack`) and than immediatly forget (`.pack_forget()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Tkinter [`after`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method instead of `time.sleep()`, as `time.sleep()` should almost never be used in a GUI. `after` schedules a function to be called after a specified time in milliseconds. You could implement it like this:

```
myFrame.after(10000, myFrame.pack_forget)
label1.after(10000,label1.pack_forget)
```

Note that `after` does not ***ensure*** a function will occur at precisely the right time, it only schedules it to occur *after* a certain amount of time. As a result of Tkinter being single-threaded, if your app is busy there may be a delay measurable in microseconds (*most likely*).